# Job context in parallel execution [Spring Batch]

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using Asynch jobLaucher for starting spring batch jobs. I tried to execute the same job parallelly but it seems the 2nd started job caused side effect to the 1st job. (It seems that the value of step_output of the 1st job overwritten by the 2nd job.
Everything works well if I use Synch JobLauncher.

My question is. Can I use jobContext in the following way?

MyTaskLetStep (implements StepExecutionListener):

```
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        ExecutionContext jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
       ...
        jobContext.put("step_output" ,outList);  
        ...
   }
```

Started Jobs looks like this one:

```
    <batch:job id="TACKJob" restartable="true" incrementer="runIdIncrementer" parent="joblistenerjob"> 
    <batch:step id="F1" next = "F2">
        <batch:tasklet ref="N_COMMAND"/> 
    </batch:step>       
    <batch:step id="F2">
        <batch:tasklet ref="Z_COMMAND"/> 
    </batch:step>       
</batch:job>
```

The referenced tasklet beans are prototype scoped beans. They implement the referred StepExecutionListener.

Do you have any advices for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried configuring your tasklet to be step scoped?

Comment: Interesting seems working with step scope. Btw. what is the difference between step and prototype?

Comment: with step scope a new bean is created for each new step where as with prototype a new bean is created whenever requested. Therefore, with prototype the same bean could be instantiated more than once per step.